# mpasm - overlapping variables in a udata directive

Tags: pic, assembly

In MPASM it appears I can do this to make paylen_lo and bytesleft have the same memory location:

```
            UDATA
paylen_hi   RES     1
bytesleft   RES     0
paylen_lo   RES     1
```

This uses the same type of trick as used with CBLOCK where 0 bytes is reserved for a location, thus causing two labels to be at the same location.

MPASM warn with "Warning[231] No memory has been reserved by this instruction" but the map file shows the location being shared correctly.

My problem is - this does not seem to be documented and thus makes me worry it's a hack. The alternatives I've tried are:

```
bytesleft  EQU  paylen_lo
           #define bytesleft paylen_lo
```

The first does not work and the second is fine. Do the more experienced PIC developers stick with defines? The only advantage of the hack above is that the symbol is created.

Comment: there are some guys around here who can definitely answer your question, my 2 cents: I'd stick to the define thing, it's clear and standard, even for non ASM guys.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Yes, I agree. The whole "no memory has been reserved" thing makes my skin crawl. It's what I'd do in C, unions notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the first method a few times, although two names for the same byte is something to avoid unless there really is some advantage.

Unfortunately, MPASM throws warnings for some perfectly normal and useful things.  You can selectively disable nuisance warnings by the warning number.  I guess I must have done that long ago in my setup code since I don't get that warning.

I don't like using #define because, just as in C, it is only a string substitution.  The assembler replaces one string with another and knows nothing more about it than that.  The first method is better since the assembler understands that the symbol is the address of a variable.

Another issue with your code is that you are using a unusual byte order.  On a 8 bit machine, the byte order of muli-byte variables is up to you.  However, there are a few cases where native data values are larger than 8 bits, and the PIC hardware assumes they are stored in least to most significant byte order.  This is therefore also how libraries are written.  You should use low byte first order unless there is a specific and special reason not to.  For example, I have stored IP addresses in high to low byte order because that is how they are sent and received in the IP protocol.  But in all such cases there must be a comment flagging the fact that the byte order is opposite from the standard expected order.

I also think naming each byte of a multi-byte variable adds more confusion due to clutter than the extra names might help with.  For example, I define multi-byte variables like this:

```
myvar    res     4           ;32 bit integer
```

In that case, I make a point of always referecing individual bytes by using the variable name plus the explicit byte offset, even when that byte offset is 0.  For example:

```
;   Increment MYVAR by one.
;
         banksel myvar
         incf    myvar+0     ;increment the low byte
         movlw   0
         addwfc  myvar+1     ;propagate carry to higher bytes
         addwfc  myvar+2
         addwfc  myvar+3
```

The "+n" syntax alerts readers to the fact that this is a multi-byte variable, and then which byte is being accessed.

Comment: There are marked differences between constant/equ and define and I try to use define when I really want string subtitution, mainly with giving names to pins. I reuse variables a little bit, especially when I want a temp but that's sometimes muddies the code; but #define might make it much worse by masking which variable you're actually using! For multiple byte variables, the method you've shown is definately better. I really try and make my code as clear as possible. Funny enough, the module I'm talking to is big endian, but I admit I didn't notice the order!

Comment: In the same vein as #defines, I've noticed that a world of hurt awaits if you use a macro like 
"testrange 5, max + 5" without using brackets around the macro variables. Macros just do text substitution too!

Comment: @carv: I rarely use #define in MPASM.  Virtualizing pins should be much more than dumb string substitutions.  You can #define a single name for the port register and bit, but what if you want to access the LAT register, or the TRIS register, or manipulate the same bit in a shadow register?  See the /INBIT and /OUTBIT commands of my preprocessor (http://www.embedinc.com/pic/prepic.txt.htm).  It also has far more capable macro handling, and lots of other stuff.  I wouldn't dream of writing MPASM or ASM30 code without it.